# Google Maps API not working & Options

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong? I have followed tutorial after tutorial and still my scroll wheel will not disable. I have the API & the options telling scroll wheel to stop but it doesn't.

The Header Section

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCOUIGHpD4lCFJ-lQ0n-sCXmkZ1_pQ8pjY&sensor=false"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 8,
      zoomControl: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      overviewMapControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
  }
</script>
```

The Body Section

```
 <div id="map_canvas">

       <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d24141.27049823528!2d-74.06035544999999!3d40.8574141!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c2f9b0a40235f7%3A0xd81a483d6e7a2235!2sTeterboro%2C+NJ!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1395840447571" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
       </div>
```

The site is live http://new.northernarchitecturalsystems.com/pages/contact.html.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `map_options` when you initialise the map, but you have called your variable `mapOptions`.

It's possible you'll see a similar error with `map_canvas` when you fix the first, but for some reason an error isn't coming up in the developer console.

If you press F12 and then go to Console when you load your live website, your first error becomes very clear, and may reveal any further problems.